# Python API returns SONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)

Tags: python, api

Input works fine, but when any standard ingredient is inputted - JSONDError is returned. I think it's in the second section, could someone identify issue?

CODE:

```
import requests


def recipe_search(ingredient):
recipes_appid ='0f89098e'
recipes_appkey ='80a8b7c8361daa22182bc3b3eb9f277e'
url = 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_keys{}'.format(ingredient, recipes_appid, recipes_appkey)
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

return(data['hits'])


def run():
ingredient = input('What ingredient is used by date first?')

results = recipe_search(ingredient)

for result in results:
    recipe = result['recipe']

    print(recipe['label'])
    print(recipe['url'])
    print()

run()
```

Comment: The API is not returning a valid response likely because you're missing a `=` after `app_keys` in the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `=` and it's supposed to be `app_key` and not `app_keys`, see the [doc here](https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api).

Change your `url` line to read:

```
url = 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_key={}'.format(ingredient, recipes_appid, recipes_appkey)
```

Also: Don't copy paste API keys. And check for the response code. The failure returned a `401` so indicating something is wrong (API key not correctly transferred in this case).

Comment: Thank you! That has worked perfectly :)